# get post based on category chosen in drop down - The ajax method

Tags: php, functions, categories, ajax

```
<div class="latest_video">
        <?php wp_dropdown_categories(); ?>
        <?php
        // the query
            $the_query = new WP_Query( array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'posts_per_page' => 10,
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'category_name' => $_REQUEST['cat']
            )  );
        ?>
        <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
            <!-- the loop -->
            <ul class="flex">
            <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
                <li class="thebox">
                    <div class="theimg"><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'large') ?></div>
                    <div class="stext3">
                        <h4><?php $categories = get_the_category();
                        if ( ! empty( $categories ) ) {
                          echo '<a class="themecolor" href="' . esc_url( get_category_link( $categories[0]->term_id ) ) . '">'  . esc_html( $categories[0]->name ) . '</a>';
                        } ?></h4>
                        <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                    </div>
                </li>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
            </ul>
            <!-- end of the loop -->
            <!-- <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?> -->
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
```

Now here onwards I am clueless How to make it work based on categories selected from the drop-down. Can someone help me to take things further or perhaps guide me how to start?

Comment: You mentioned AJAX in the title, but your code isn't using AJAX. It's simply trying to get the category's name on page load.

Comment: Hi Jack, somehow this is used → wp_ajax_my_action and wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action, where my_action is the value of the GET or POST variable action. But I am not versed enough to accomplish this. [Further Reading](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/how-to-use-ajax-in-wordpress/)

Comment: You're going to have to write some javascript for this, and display the posts via JS rather than PHP. You should be able to use the REST API though, no need to write an AJAX handler

Comment: Using AJAX is more complicated than that. It requires to gather data, send them to server, build a response, and then handle the response. I could post a non-ajax solution if you wish.

Comment: @Tom J nowel, Is there any example on your website or anywhere that I can use as a source point? Help will be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can get your code to work by tweaking it a little bit. First, you need to create a form that includes the categories. Then, submit the form the the same page to apply it to the query.

```
<div class="latest_video">

    <!-- We add a form that submits the request the the same page -->
    <form method="get">
        <?php wp_dropdown_categories( 'show_count=1&hierarchical=1' ); ?>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="view" />
    </form>

    <?php
    // the query
        $the_query = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => 10,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'category_name' => $_GET['cat']
        )  );
    ?>
    <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
        <!-- the loop -->
        <ul class="flex">
        <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
            <li class="thebox">
                <div class="theimg"><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'large') ?></div>
                <div class="stext3">
                    <h4><?php $categories = get_the_category();
                    if ( ! empty( $categories ) ) {
                      echo '<a class="themecolor" href="' . esc_url( get_category_link( $categories[0]->term_id ) ) . '">'  . esc_html( $categories[0]->name ) . '</a>';
                    } ?></h4>
                    <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                </div>
            </li>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        </ul>
        <!-- end of the loop -->
        <!-- <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?> -->
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Now, the initial load will include all the categories in the `WP_Query`, but once the user chooses a category and submits the form, the page will reload and the `WP_Query` will be updated. Make sure you don't add `action` to your form, so it will be submitted to the current page.

If you want to reload the page without clicking the submit button, you can add this JS snippet and remove the button:

```
var dropdown = document.getElementById("cat");
function onCatChange() {
    if ( dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value > 0 ) {
        location.href = window.location.href + "?cat="+dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
    }
}
dropdown.onchange = onCatChange;
```

For further information, please refer to the [`wp_dropdown_categories()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_categories) codex page.

Comment: `<?php wp_dropdown_categories( 'show_count=1&hierarchical=1' ); ?>` → In this method the all category option is notn populating. means all category posts not populating.